# ios: Communicating between host and USB-Connected device

Tags: ios

Android provides "adb" as a mechanism for communicating between host and apps on a USB-connected device. This is useful for automation (e.g. execute some code on the device and collect the results). We need this capability for iOS. Does a similar mechanism exist for iOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a similar mechanism. The underlying technology/service is called usbmuxd. It is basically a multiplexing service that allows you to connect to your iOS device via USB using the TCP protocol. Apple uses this service for any communication between your iOS device and iTunes or Xcode, e.g., to install apps via iTunes.

If you want to leverage this mechanism, there is a library that provides a high level API for iOS. They have reverse engineered the whole protocol including things like remote debugging via lldb and app installation.

http://www.libimobiledevice.org

If you just want to sideload compiled binary bundles into your own app you might get away with using my library. It allows you transmit arbitrary data via USB to your app and supports both iOS and tvOS.

http://www.github.com/jensmeder/DarkLightning

Comment: Is there any way to implement reverse proxy in iOS i.e. using usbmuxd we can connect the host to device but I want to connect the device with the host over TCP.